# Why can a function take (int *&) as a parameter?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Following is a code to split an array. The
first    output  array   will    contain     the     input   array   entries     in  between     the     given   two     indices     and     the     second 
output  array   will    contain the rest    of  the entries.

```
void splitArray(int *arr, int size, int ind1, int ind2,
     int *&first, int &firstSize, int *&second, int &secondSize){
    firstSize = ind2 - ind1 + 1;
    secondSize = size - firstSize;
    first = new int[firstSize];
    second = new int[secondSize];
    for (int i = 0; i < ind1; i++)
    second[i] = arr[i];
    for (int i = ind1; i <= ind2; i++)
    first[i - ind1] = arr[i];
    for (int i = ind2 + 1; i < size; i++)
    second[i - firstSize] = arr[i];
    }
```

The thing I can understand why it has parameters like int `*&first` and `int *&second`, arent they are same as just `int first` and `int second` but in this code they are used as pointers to dynamic arrays.

Comment: No, they aren't - `int*&` is a reference to a pointer to `int`.

Comment: Here, `&` means "This is a C++ reference", not "take the address of". They use the same symbol for two different things which are only slightly more related to each other than they are to "bitwise and".

Comment: `*&first` would be the same as `first` if they were expressions and `*` and `&` were operators, but this is a declaration so `*` and `&` are not operators but parts of the type.

Answer (score 3):

`T *&foo` declares a reference to a pointer to `T`. Don't confuse the ampersand in declarations and definitions with the address-of operator.

References to pointers are used if the called function needs to be able to modify the value of the pointer passed to it:

```
void bar(int *&ptr) {
    ptr = 42;  // change the value of the pointer  (pseudo ... 42 is most likely
    *ptr = 42; // change the value of the pointee   not a valid pointer value)
}

// ...

int *foo = nullptr;
bar(foo);
// foo == 42;
```

Hint: Read types from right to left: `T *&` --> `&* T` --> reference (`&`) to pointer (`*`) to type `T`.